# Transformation XML to Xml using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I query a data from MS access and export to a expected xml file by using an our xslt file.
Then I export the xml data for creating the new xml file by using xslt. So I have a problem to create subgroup.

This is my data from MS access.

```
<dataroot>
    <qryDataXML>
        <ProjectName>Test Project One</ProjectName>
        <ItemConcate>01 - TEST 1</ItemConcate>
        <ComponentName>Table</ComponentName>
        <ComponentNo>1.01</ComponentNo>
        <SizeHeight>78</SizeHeight>
        <SizeWidth>60</SizeWidth>
        <SizeDepth>35</SizeDepth>
        <PartName>SHELF_ADJ</PartName>
        <SumOfPartQty>1</SumOfPartQty>
    </qryDataXML>
    <qryDataXML>
        <ProjectName>Test Project One</ProjectName>
        <ItemConcate>01 - TEST 1</ItemConcate>
        <ComponentName>Table</ComponentName>
        <ComponentNo>1.01</ComponentNo>
        <SizeHeight>78</SizeHeight>
        <SizeWidth>60</SizeWidth>
        <SizeDepth>35</SizeDepth>
        <PartName>SHELF_FIXED</PartName>
        <SumOfPartQty>4</SumOfPartQty>
    </qryDataXML>
    <qryDataXML>
        <ProjectName>Test Project One</ProjectName>
        <ItemConcate>01 - TEST 1</ItemConcate>
        <ComponentName>Chair</ComponentName>
        <ComponentNo>1.02</ComponentNo>
        <SizeHeight>80</SizeHeight>
        <SizeWidth>60</SizeWidth>
        <SizeDepth>35</SizeDepth>
        <PartName>SHELF_ADJ</PartName>
        <SumOfPartQty>2</SumOfPartQty>
    </qryDataXML>
    <qryDataXML>
        <ProjectName>Test Project One</ProjectName>
        <ItemConcate>01 - TEST 1</ItemConcate>
        <ComponentName>Chair</ComponentName>
        <ComponentNo>1.02</ComponentNo>
        <SizeHeight>80</SizeHeight>
        <SizeWidth>60</SizeWidth>
        <SizeDepth>35</SizeDepth>
        <PartName>SHELF_FIXED</PartName>
        <SumOfPartQty>3</SumOfPartQty>
    </qryDataXML>
</dataroot>
```

This expected result is

```
<Root>
    <Project Name="Test Project One">
    <ItemName Name="01 - TEST 1"/>
    <Products>
        <Product Name="Table">
            <Height>78</Height>
            <Width>60</Width>
            <Depth>35</Depth>
                <ItemNumber>1.01</ItemNumber>
                <Prompts>
                    <Prompt Name="SHELF_ADJ">
                        <Value>1</Value>
                    </Prompt>
                    <Prompt Name="SHELF_FIXED">
                        <Value>4</Value>
                    </Prompt>
                </Prompts>
        </Product>
        <Product Name="Chair">
            <Height>80</Height>
            <Width>60</Width>
            <Depth>35</Depth>
            <ItemNumber>1.02</ItemNumber>
            <Prompts>
                    <Prompt Name="SHELF_ADJ">
                        <Value>2</Value>
                    </Prompt>
                    <Prompt Name="SHELF_FIXED">
                        <Value>3</Value>
                    </Prompt>
            </Prompts>
        </Product>
    </Products>
</Root>
```

Now, this is my xslt file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" version="1.0"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<Root>
    <Project>
        <xsl:attribute name="Name"><xsl:value-of select="ProjectName"/></xsl:attribute>
        <ItemName>
            <xsl:attribute name="Name"><xsl:value-of select="ItemConcate"/></xsl:attribute>
        </ItemName>
        <Products>
            <xsl:for-each select="dataroot/qryDataXML"/>
                <Product>           
                    <xsl:attribute name="Name">
                        <xsl:value-of select="ComponentName"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <Height><xsl:value-of select="SizeHeight"/></Height>
                    <Width><xsl:value-of select="SizeWidth"/></Width>
                    <Depth><xsl:value-of select="SizeDepth"/></Depth>
                    
                    <ItemNumber><xsl:value-of select="ComponentNo"/></ItemNumber>

                    <Prompts>
                            <Prompt>
                                <xsl:for-each select="'PartName','SumSumOfPartQty'"/>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="Name">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="//PartName"/>
                                    </xsl:attribute>
                                    <Value><xsl:value-of select="//SumOfPartQty"/></Value>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </Prompt>
                    </Prompts>
                </Product>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Products> 
    </Project>
</Root>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please give some advice for what I should do.

Comment: What is your **actual** outcome and **how** it differs from what you're expecting?

Comment: Look into grouping in XSLT, some info is at https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info

Comment: First thing: which version of XSLT does your processor support? Your stylesheet declares `version="1.0"` but uses some constructs that require XSLT 2.0 or higher (not to mention it has errors that will bomb in any version). Anyway, for *grouping* start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info) and come back if you run into a **specific** problem.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: missed your note, otherwise I shouldn't edit this post...

Comment: A completely standard grouping problem; please do some research and come back if you have problems.

Comment: Thank you for all suggestion.

Now I have a problem with using my xslt file with ms access.
Can the xslt 2.0 or higher use with MS access?
I have try to use 3.0. It shows "Specified transform failed to successfully transform your data. The text associated with this error code could not be found".
Then I change to version 1.0, it seem run but tell "does not know 'for-each-group'".